# QScintilla autocomplete on custom lexer in python

Tags: autocomplete, lexer, qscintilla

All,

I'm using QScintilla to syntax-highlight and autocomplete my domain specific language (DSL).

I wrote a custom lexer by re-implementing (QsciLexerCustom) and I'm trying to use the auto-completion.
My problem is that the auto-completion doesn't work like I want.
I'd like my custom lexer to work like the QsciLexerPython. That is, if i add 'toto.titi.tata' to the api, when i type 'toto.' in my qscintilla editor, it suggests me 'titi.tata'. As of now, it is suggesting me toto.titi.tata. :(

I tried to add 'autoCompletionWordSeparators' to my lexer but it is not working.
How can i make my custom lexer auto-complete work like the QsciLexerPython?
Thanks a lot !

```
Lexer = customlexer(self.text)
api = QsciAPIs(Lexer)
api.add('toto.titi.tata')
api.prepare()
Lexer.setAPIs(api)
self.text.setLexer(Lexer)

class lexer(QsciLexerCustom):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QsciLexerCustom.__init__(self, parent)

    def autoCompletionWordSeparators(self):
        return ['.']
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but I have implemented autocomplete for a custom lexer in QScintilla, but I had to also create a custom parser to find classes and function definitions in the code. Using SendScintilla(), you can easily use the low-level Scintilla api calls through QScintilla to show the autocomplete box, however filling it up requires that custom parser.

Comment: This might also help: http://qscintilla.com/

Answer (score 2):

The current QScintilla APIs provide no way to do this.

The main obstacle is that many of the virtual methods you need to reimplement in a `QsciLexerCustom` subclass aren't public. This is why the code in your example doesn't work - your `autoCompletionWordSeparators` method is ignored when the lexer is set, and the base-class method from `QsciLexer` is called instead (which returns an empty list).

You might also think you could use [QsciScintilla.setAutoCompletionWordSeparators](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/classQsciScintilla.html#a4ba18e98a98310113fb30d8ada30fe14) to work around this, but alas, this only works if no lexer has been set!

The only way to solve this issue is to either implement auto-completion yourself (which is doable, but a *lot* of work), or make a feature request on the [Qscintilla mailing list](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/qscintilla) to get the necessary virtual methods added to the public API for `QsciLexerCustom`.

The methods in question are [listed here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/classQsciLexer.html#pub-methods) (the names are shown in bold black, rather than as a link).